# R:  += (plus equals) and ++ (plus plus) equivalent from c++/c#/java, etc.?

Tags: r, operators, variable-assignment, increment

Does R have a concept of `+=` (plus equals) or `++` (plus plus) as c++/c#/others do?

Comment: No, to do `x += 1` or `x++` - `x = x + 1` works.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

No, it doesn't, see: [R Language Definition: Operators](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Operators)

Answer (score 74):

Following @GregaKešpret you can make an infix operator:

```
`%+=%` = function(e1,e2) eval.parent(substitute(e1 <- e1 + e2))
x = 1
x %+=% 2 ; x
```

Comment: (+1), but a word of warning. Typing `x = %+=% y/2` returns `x = (x + y)/2`. Adding parenthesis, i.e. `x = %+=% (y/2)` solves the problem.

Comment: @knrumsey Why is that? I would've guessed division would be a higher precedence operator.

Comment: @DavidKelley Not sure. I'm with you there. I ran into this issue working on a project once and it took me an hour to find the issue.

Comment: Remember you're running a function, not doing an addition. Functions have the highest precedence so without the parenthesis it parses the y as the function input with the division being the next step down the chain. The parenthesis elevate the (y/2) operation to the top of the chain.

Answer (score 37):

R doesn't have a concept of `increment operator` (as for example ++ in C). However, it is not difficult to implement one yourself, for example:

```
inc <- function(x)
{
 eval.parent(substitute(x <- x + 1))
}
```

In that case you would call

```
x <- 10
inc(x)
```

However, it introduces function call overhead, so it's **slower** than typing `x <- x + 1` yourself. If I'm not mistaken `increment operator` was introduced to make job for compiler easier, as it could convert the code to those machine language instructions directly.

Comment: This function cannot return the value and then increment like a postincrement ++. It's more similar to += or preincrement ++.

Comment: Wrong! Incrementation wasn't introduced to make the job of compiler easier. `INC` instruction was introduced **in processors** primarily for implementing counters (cf. Intel Software Developer's Manual). I will update the answer.

Answer (score 27):

R doesn't have these operations because (most) objects in R are immutable.  They do not change.  Typically, when it looks like you're modifying an object, you're actually modifying a copy.

Comment: While immutability is a great/desirable property for objects (read: less bugs) I don't think immutability relates to the += question.  In other languages += can be applied to immutable types (like strings in .net).  The operation simply creates a new object and assigns the given variable to that new object.  Immutability is maintained and the variable is updated.

Comment: Good point.  Immutability certainly makes this sort of operation less natural, however.

Answer (score 15):

Increment and decrement by 10.

```
require(Hmisc)
inc(x) <- 10 

dec(x) <- 10
```

Comment: These functions appear to have been removed from `Hmisc` as of version 4.1.0.

Comment: @llasram looking at that notation, I cannot blame anyone.

Answer (score 9):

We released a package, roperators, to help with this kind of thing. You can read more about it here: https://happylittlescripts.blogspot.com/2018/09/make-your-r-code-nicer-with-roperators.html

```
install.packages('roperators')
require(roperators)

x <- 1:3
x %+=% 1; x
x %-=% 3; x
y <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
y %+=% 'text'; y
y %-=% 'text'; y

# etc
```

Answer (score 7):

We can override `+`. If unary `+` is used and its argument is itself an unary `+` call, then increment the relevant object in the calling environment.

```
`+` <- function(e1,e2){
  # if binary `+`, keep original behavior
  if(!missing(e2)) return(base::`+`(e1, e2))
  
  # if inner call isn't unary `+` called on language object,
  # keep original behavior
  inner_call <- substitute(e1)
  inner_call_is_plus_on_lng <-
    length(inner_call) == 2 &&
    identical(inner_call[[1]], quote(`+`)) &&
    is.language(inner_call[[2]])
  if(!inner_call_is_plus_on_lng) return(base::`+`(e1))
  
  eval.parent(substitute(X <- X + 1, list(X = inner_call[[2]])))
}

x <- 10

++x
x
#> [1] 11
```

other operations don't change :

```
x + 2
#> [1] 13
x ++ 2
#> [1] 13
+x
#> [1] 11
x
#> [1] 11
```

I can't really recommend it since you're messing with primitives which are optimised for a reason.

Comment: I like this answer. but ++1 ==> " Error in 1 <- 1 + 1 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment" !

Comment: Thanks, I reworked the answer, now `++1` returns 1

Comment: I think ++1 should return 2!

Comment: I don't think so, `++` is incrementing an object in place, it works only on symbols, `1` isn't a symbol, I can't change the value of `1`, so what happens is that I fall back to the default behavior of `+`.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `inplace`

```
library(inplace)
x <- 1
x %+<-% 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `i++` in an array to increment the index, you can try `i <- i + 1`, for example,

```r
k = 0
a = 1:4
for (i in 1:4) 
    cat(a[k <- k + 1], " ")
# 1 2 3 4
```

but here `<-` can NOT be replaced with `=`, which does not update the index,

```r
k = 0
a = 1:4
for (i in 1:4) 
    cat(a[k = k + 1], " ")
# 1 1 1 1
```

since `=` and `<-` are not always equivalent, as said in `` ?`<-` ``

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler approach to increment a variable.

```
inc = 1

for(i in 1:10){
    print(paste("Value of inc: ", inc))
    inc = sum(c(inc, 1))
}
```

You will get results as follows

```
[1] "Value of inc:  1"
[1] "Value of inc:  2"
[1] "Value of inc:  3"
[1] "Value of inc:  4"
[1] "Value of inc:  5"
[1] "Value of inc:  6"
[1] "Value of inc:  7"
[1] "Value of inc:  8"
[1] "Value of inc:  9"
[1] "Value of inc:  10"
```