# What is the equivalent of += (plus equals) in R

Tags: r, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R:  += and ++ equivalent from c++/c#/java, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738831/r-and-equivalent-from-c-c-java-etc)

Does R (specifically a `data.frame`) have a version of the += operator? I would like to say:

```
my.df[foo > 50,"foo"] -= 10
```

But the best I can come up with so far is:

```
my.df[foo > 50,"foo"] <- my.df[foo > 50,"foo"] - 10
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: No. There is no such equivalent.

Comment: @joran I must congratulate you on your search-fu. I knew this had been asked before, but couldn't navigate the search either on SO or in Google.

Comment: @Andrie "[r] += increment" did it for me, but it took 2-3 tries before I got there.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this may have been asked before but I had no idea how to go about searching it. I tried a few variants but got nowhere.

Comment: @joran: the "+=" is ignored. "[r] increment" is sufficient.

Comment: Also duplicates the even earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768686/r-self-reference

Comment: That earlier question also usefully references `:=` in `data.table`, which I use often. But, unfortunately, in this case I'm using `data.frame` and don't have access to that.