# Self reference when indexing into a vector

Tags: r

In R, is there a way to reference a vector from within the vector?

Say I have vectors with long names:

```
my.vector.with.a.long.name <- 1:10
```

Rather than this:

```
my.vector.with.a.long.name[my.vector.with.a.long.name > 5]
```

Something like this would be nice:

```
> my.vector.with.a.long.name[~ > 5]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or alternatively indexing by a function would be convenient:

```
> my.vector.with.a.long.name[is.even]
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Is there a package that already supports this?

Comment: Not sure why can't you create your own functions that will do what suggest, e.g., `myFunc <- function(x, y) x[x > y] ; is.even <- function(x) x[(x %% 2) == 0] ; myFunc(my.vector.with.a.long.name, 5) ; is.even(my.vector.with.a.long.name)`

Comment: or use tab to autocomplete your (needlessly) long names?

Comment: Not really interested in solutions the specific examples I gave, just wondering if this syntax is supported already in some way.

Comment: It's a bit what the package `data.table` does for data frames. You can start by taking a look there?

Comment: Not tried, but maybe `require(magrittr);  my.stupid.name %>% [>5]` or similar to that?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, was thinking the same but couldn't find the correct syntax

Comment: A [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5738831/324364) question which might provide some ideas on how you'd go about implementing this if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, `magrittr` seems to offer the closest option.  May try hacking the actual feature together at some point.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't think it will work with magrittr, see: http://renkun.me/blog/2014/08/08/difference-between-magrittr-and-pipeR.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use pipes which allow self-referencing with `.`:

```
library(pipeR)
my.vector.with.a.long.name %>>% `[`(.>5)
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
my.vector.with.a.long.name %>>% `[`(.%%2==0)
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Comment: Yep.  My solution was `foo %>>% (.[(.>5)])` which does the same as yours, I believe... but you win the CodeGolf here :-)

Answer (score 5):

The `Filter` function helps with this

```
my.vector.with.a.long.name <- 1:10
Filter(function(x) x%%2==0, my.vector.with.a.long.name)
```

or

```
is.even <- function(x) x%%2==0
Filter(is.even, my.vector.with.a.long.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're basically asking if you can use something other than the variable's name to refer to it. The short answer is no. That is the whole idea behind variable names. If you want a shorter name, name it something shorter.

The longer answer is it depends. You're really just using logical indexing in its long form. To make it shorter/refer to it more than once without having to type that enormous name, just save it in a vector like so:

```
gt5 <- my.vector.with.a.long.name > 5
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE...

my.vector.with.a.long.name[gt5]
[1] 6 7 8 9 10
```

You can do the same thing with a function as long as it returns the indexes or a logical vector.

The `dplyr` package allows you to do some cool chaining things, where you use the `%.%` operator to take the LHS of the operator and input into the first argument of the RHS function call.

It's cool to use in the dplyr package by saying things like:

```
data %.% group_by(group.var) %.% summarize(Mean=mean(ID))
```

instead of:

```
summarize(group_by(data, group.var), Mean=mean(ID)).
```

Comment: You can, but this is extremely wasteful of memory since AFAIK a whole new object `gt5` is created when it's entirely unnecessary to do so.

Comment: Yes, gt5 creates a new logical vector, but obviously this is a trivial example. If you're going to re-use the indexing or it's complicated to create, I like to create these indexing objects.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: Do the profiling and you'll see that exactly the same happens when you use the code given above. This is exactly the same as the code of OP, except spelled out explicity. So the memory footprint is the same afaik.

Comment: @JorisMeys but the vector `my.vector.with.a.long.name > 5` gets removed at the next garbage collection, where as `gt5` doesn't.

Comment: @SeñorO Which is why I always stress in my class that temporary objects serve readability more than anything else, and should be removed whenever possible. Not only for memory issues, also to avoid bugs with generic counters called `i` for example.

Next to that, it might be beneficial to keep it, in order to avoid having to recalculate the same thing a couple of times (as you see often happening in code, especially with the constructs OP refers to).

Comment: @JorisMeys Exactly. I frequently create constructs like this that I use to refer to sets of indicies multiple times. If it's a one off thing like the gt5, I will just type it. It's not that much of an encumbrance with tab completion.

Comment: Has someone remapped `>` on your set-up? The results do not match.

Comment: @James No, I typed this all in by hand. I'm an idiot and typed the results for less than instead of greater than.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create another object with a shorter name:

```
my.vector.with.a.long.name <- 1:10

mm = my.vector.with.a.long.name 

mm
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

mm[mm<5]
[1] 1 2 3 4

mm[mm>5]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Why use other packages and complex code?