# Updating a vector efficiently in R , or a += equivelent

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I know that there is no += operator in R ([R:  += (plus equals) and ++ (plus plus) equivalent from c++/c#/java, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738831/r-plus-equals-and-plus-plus-equivalent-from-c-c-java-etc))

The following function iterating over a bunch of things and accumulating the difference is slower than expected.
The largest runtime component is a simple addition, and Rprof shows that ~20% of the runtime is garbage collection in the following function. This feels like we are constructing many copies of the ~1e7 records in myVector and discarding them, whereas an in-place operation shouldn't have this overhead

```
testCase <- function(f) {
  difference<-rep(0,f)
   # replicate approximate code structure of original test case
  for(i in 1:10){
    if(runif(1,0,1)>.1) {
      partialDiff<-dd(f)#
    }
    else {
        partialDiff<-dd2(f)#
    }
    difference<-difference+partialDiff
  }
  return(difference)
}


dd <- function(f) {
  result <- (1:f)
  return(result)
}
dd2 <- function(f) {
  result <- sqrt(1:f)
  return(result)
}

# now for actual profiling ; build the D i want 50 times, just to get a statistical profile of what is going on there
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile(), gc.profiling = TRUE, interval=".01")
for(i in 1:50) {
    d<-testCase(10000000)
}
Rprof()

require(proftools)
summaryRprof(tmp)
pd <- readProfileData(tmp)
#funSummary(pd);callSummary(pd);pathSummary(pd);hotPaths(pd)
plot(pd)
```

using Rprof to detail the runtime i get the following breakdown of runtime with dd sequence creation (as expected) , calc2 showing sqrt as the biggest cost(as expected), but the largest cost in f is the effort of doing the addition "difference<-difference+partialDiff". This is not expected.

Can anyone explain why, or offer an efficent workaround?

[image: RProf breakdown]

- Testing the length of difference, it isn't altered from its
  initialization.
- class(partialDiff)==class(difference)=="numeric"
- length(partialDiff)==length(difference) == about 17M in the test case
  profiled here.
- note f returns a f by 1 vector, not a f by 10 matrix

edit: in response to comments i have replaced my simple code structure with a complete test case program

Comment: the pic was created by Rprof(tmp <- tempfile()...); pd <- readProfileData(tmp); plot(pd); this utalises the proftools package

Comment: If you can make a fully reproducible example I suspect more people will look at it for you.

Comment: @Spacedman updated with complete test case, rather than just the function outline.