# In-place assignment in R without writing the variable name twice?

Tags: python, r

I generally try to avoid code duplication, even in single rows. However, I find myself writing lines like this in R a lot:

```
# R code
my_long_vector_var_name <- append(my_long_vector_var_name, new_var)
my_long_int_name <- my_long_int_name + 1
```

In Python, not only are there way less letters in a row - I also do not have to write the same variable twice, which potentially reduces errors:

```
my_long_vector_var_name.append(new_var)
my_long_int_name += 1
```

For the second one, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738831/r-plus-equals-and-plus-plus-equivalent-from-c-c-java-etc) indicates that there truely is no comparable "short" way in R. The question, however, is more than 6 years old. Is there still no better way to do this in R?

Comment: I don't think there are shortcuts, no. Generally, R objects are immutable and copied when modified, one has to explicitly overwrite the original variable by assigning the copy.

Comment: If you grow vectors often, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Roland: I mainly do it for data cleaning: "If the table contains a certain element, add it to the processing vector..." "If I use realtime data, add this column to the list of factors...". I don't actually grow any data frames / vectors of data ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`magrittr` has a `%<>%` operator which pipes and updates an object.

```
library('magrittr')

v <- c(1, 2)

v %<>% append(3)
v
#> [1] 1 2 3

v %<>% add(1)
v
#> [1] 2 3 4
```

Comment: While I like the Python dot notation (v.append(3)) better, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for in R.

Answer (score 1):

for the first question to some extend you can use %>% operator from dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
my_long_vector<-rep(c("A","B","C"),10)%>%c("NEW VALUE")
```

Comment: While `dplyr` uses the pipe, it is from the `magrittr` package, which has a more appropriate operator (see Paul's answer)